# how to handle firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential error

Tags: javascript, firebase, error-handling, firebase-authentication

I am using `firebase phone authentication` to authenticate users on firebase. It is working fine, after successfully authenticating user with xyz phone number now i want to update phone number to abc in short i am trying to update user's mobile number.
I have found firebase web api to update user's existing mobile number which works as following.

following function will send otp on new phone number which user want to register.

```
function sentOTPToNewNumber() {
        var phoneNumber = document.getElementById("newPhone").value;
        var appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;
        firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
            .then(function (confirmationResult) {

                // SMS sent. Prompt user to type the code from the message, then sign the
                // user in with confirmationResult.confirm(code).

                window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error)
            });
    }
```

after receiving otp on new number we have to verify the number following function is doing that.

```
    function codeVerification() {
            var verificationCode = document.getElementById("verification").value;


       try {
                //at this line i am facing issue.
                var credential = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(confirmationResult.verificationId, verificationCode) 

                console.log(credential);
                var result = userLocal.updatePhoneNumber(credential);    
                console.log(result);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);     
            }
        }
```

i want to handle an error in case of user enters wrong otp in codeVerification function.following api which we are using throws error when we try to enter wrong otp but i am unable to handle the error within `try catch` block.

```
firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(confirmationResult.verificationId, verificationCode)
```

i have found following description on [google firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider) but unable to understand how to handle error. The `try catch` block which i have implemented does not caught error thrown by firebase. i also try to use `then(function(){}).catch(function(error){})` it says then is not a function.
[image]

following error i am getting in my console which i want to handle.
Note: I am able to successfully update user phone number if user enters correct otp. only issue is I want to handle situation when code is not proper or  to know if update is successful or not.

[image]

thank you for your time and support it will be very helpful.

Comment: Hey, i faced same issue if you solve it Can you check this question please! !/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59017495/update-phone-number-in-firebase-authentication-react-native

Comment: Your question was very helpful! Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `userLocal.updatePhoneNumber(credential)` call returns a `Promise` object (see [`updatePhoneNumber` docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#updatePhoneNumber)), which gets rejected when something goes wrong. However, the way you're trying to catch this is incorrect, which is why you're unable to handle the error properly.

To handle the `Promise` rejection, chain `.then().catch()` after `userLocal.updatePhoneNumber`, like so:

```js
userLocal.updatePhoneNumber(credential)
    .then(/* Update successful */)
    .catch(function(error) {
        // Update failed
    });
```

If you are using `async/await` in your code, you can keep the `try-catch` code that you currently have, but perform the following changes:

1. Make `codeVerification` an `async` function
2. `await` the call to `userLocal.updatePhoneNumber`

```js
async function codeVerification() {
    ...
    try {
        ...
        var result = await userLocal.updatePhoneNumber(credential); 
        //           ^^^^^ notice the `await` keyword above
        // Update successful
    } catch (error) {
        // Update failed
    }
}
```

The two solutions above are basically the same, they just differ in syntax.

Comment: Thank you, i have mistaken the promise instead of using it with `updatePhoneNumber` i was using it with `firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential`. I read that `updatePhoneNumber` will return "promise containing void" but unable to understand how to use it.

Comment: Thank you for showing another way to handle error in case of async I was unaware of that.

Comment: Cool, glad you figured it out :) **promise containing void** means that the promise's  `.then()` callback function will not receive any arguments (or when using `async/await`, it will just return `undefined`).

Comment: Can you check this question please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59017495/update-phone-number-in-firebase-authentication-react-native